# How to use preference from other didSet variable in custom Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didset

I have a custom cell for a collectionView and inside I have 3 didSet variables. My problem is that I need to use 1 preference from each didSet to display on a label but I can't figure out a way to do so. Any suggestions?

```
class VideosCell: UICollectionViewCell {


var playlistDataFromAPI: playListsnippet?  {
    didSet{
        guard let pubDate = playlistDataFromAPI?.snippet.publishedAt else {return}
    }
}

var videoSnippet: videoSnippet? {
    didSet{
        guard let duration = videoSnippet?.contentDetails.duration else {return}

    }
}

var channelData: channelSnippet? {
    didSet{
        guard let channelName = channelData?.snippet.title else {return}

    }
}
```

Now I want to use pubDate, duration, and channelName all together to display on a label such as: label.text = channelName, duration, pubDate

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are just setting local variables that will no longer exist as soon as the `didSet` clause exits. Perhaps you want to set private properties in your cell rather local constants?

Answer (score 0):

In your UIView or UIViewController subclass, I recommend declaring a nested struct called Content that has properties for any values you need to display.

Then have an instance var of type Content, and you can access its properties from anywhere in the class.

Bundling all such properties together has several nice benefits, such as being able to export all the current stuff the user is seeing in one line of code to JSON for logging (if you make it Codable), cleaner testing, etc.